# Is the height of first century Judeans evidence against the authenticity of the Shroud of Turin?

Tags: history, nature-of-man

Does the fact that the average height of Jews in the Roman Province of Judea in the first century was 5'0 impact negatively on the authenticity of the shroud since the height of the figure on the shroud is 5'11 or 6'0?

Now the shroud may very well be from the first century due to recent carbon dating but it still does not explain why the man in the shroud is 6 feet tall.

Comment: This sounds more like history or anthropology than theology.

Comment: @RyanShack The research backing *Does the fact that the average height of Jews in the Roman Province of Judea in the first century was 5'0*? And I believe MattGutting is right.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-Christian history.

Comment: @Flimzy I don't agree with your close reason. I think primarily opinion based is about right, though. The Shroud is a Christian relic. That is on-topic.

Comment: @fredsbend: I realize it's a "Christian relic," but this question doesn't relate to the "Christianity" of it.

Comment: @Flimzy It is about the Shroud's authenticity. That makes this a Truth question, but specifically, wants to know if a particular fact is evidence against the Shroud's authenticity. That makes it primarily opinion based. Either way, I think that does relate to Christianity, just not in a way that this site can or will handle.

Comment: @fredsbend: I see it as a question asking "Does the fact that the average height of people during X time period was 5'0" prove that a historical account of a 6'0" person existing is false?" Whether the shroud is considered a Christian relic is irrelevant. The OP is asking a question about its historical authenticity.

Comment: This also seems to be a very poor question, because it seems to miss the definition of "average", thinking that "average" means "all" and not "average."

Comment: @Flimzy So it actually is a mathematical question. :P

Comment: @Zoe: Indeed :)

Comment: The height of the man on the shroud cannot be determined using a flat measurement. See here:  http://www.shroud.com/pdfs/ssiheight.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**What if Jesus was exceptionally tall?**

An average result tends to exclude some exceptional value. For example,

> Suppose there are 100 people; 99 of them are 5 feet tall and only one of them is 7
>   feet tall.
>
> Average height= ((99x5)+7)/100 = (495+7)/100 = **5.02**

[The Bible doesn't tell us about the physical appearance of Jesus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17214/3889). We don't know how tall was Jesus. Hence, we can neither prove nor disprove the authenticity of the Shroud of Turin based on it's dimension.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering**

From the scientific method, there would be discrepancy calling to question the authenticity of the shroud based on the height of the image only if 1) the actual height of Jesus was known, 2) a claim was made that the image on the cloth is his image, and 3) the height of image when compared with his known height could not be reconciled within acceptable scientific margins.

---

*Has the Church said that the relic that is the Holy Shroud of Turin is the actual "clean linen cloth" in which Joseph of Arimathea wrapped the body of Jesus Christ?* [cf. [Mt 27:59 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+27%3A59&version=RSVCE)].
**No!**

According to [The Holy Shroud (of Turin) | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13762a.htm):

> That the authenticity of the Shroud of Turin is taken for granted, in
>   various pronouncements of the Holy See cannot be disputed.

**So to the Holy See [and many others], the relic is authentic, but the Holy See has not declared this relic was the burial shroud of the LORD.**

---

Further reading:

It is said that this is the most studied artifact in history, therefore there are tons of material out there. Here is a link to one:

- [Shroud Exhibit and Museum, Inc. (iSEAM)](http://shroudnm.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The average height of a Jew in the first century was not 5', but up to about 5' 10".  The image on the Shroud cannot be accurately measured for a variety of reasons (stretching of the cloth, knees are bent, etc.), but the best estimation is about 5' 10" which comes from world renown Shroud expert Barrie Schwortz, the documenting photographer on the 1978 STURP expedition and the creator and maintainer of Shroud.com, the first and most exhaustive site for Shroud information.

Height and weight: 2 References for one to consider...
William Mecheam, Archaeologist & Shroud researcher - https://www.shroud.com/meacham2.htm
Isabel Piczek, noted monumental artist, theoretical physicist and Shroud historian - https://www.shroud.com/faq.htm#1
A site that discusses heights of Jews - http://www.naturalheightgrowth.com/2012/12/20/how-tall-is-the-height-of-jesus-christ/

Recommendation: Visit shroudnm.com, click search and use the search engine to search any of the Shroud sites listed (just click the button to the left of the site you want to search, type your criteria, like "how tall is the man on the Shroud" and click the search button).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have a few sources for some of your statements? Average height and best estimation of the height of the person on the shroud specifically need support. Please [edit] that in.

Comment: Good references. I +1'd. I also removed the reference to my previous comment. Comments do get deleted, especially when they have been obsolete for a while.

Comment: Height of man on shroud is here: http://www.shroud.com/pdfs/ssiheight.pdf

Comment: Excellent article, Daisy.  Dorthoy Crispino has done some excellent research on the Shroud.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know Zaccheus was a "wee little man" who had to climb up into a Sycamore tree to see Jesus pass by. If we assume that Zaccheus was 4 feet hing, and if the average height was five feet, then there must have been a six foot person in the population.

Answer (score 0):

One of the earliest researchers on the height of Jesus from the Shroud image was Msgr. Giulio Ricci, a Vatican official.  He estimated the height to be about 5' 4".  He did a sculpture of the body on the cross.  It is a dramatic presentation, and a focal point in the Museum of the Holy Shroud in Wabash, Indiana.  There are several Ricci books in English available in used book shops.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is actually not a great fit for this site and will likely be voted closed (preventing further answers). There are thousands of other questions here, though, that you might be able to answer; I would love to read them. I hope to see you post again soon.